# Set view does not work after Fitbounds

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, setview

I have a map and a layergroup.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([27.6758,85.3313], 12);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/8ae544230be74379927e6dee5d416398/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {}).addTo(map);

layergroup = new L.featureGroup();

js_arr = [[27.675765991210938,85.33130645751953],[27.675764083862305,85.33131408691406],[27.675764083862305,85.33131408691406],[27.675764083862305,85.33131408691406]]; 

layer.boundary_geom = L.polygon(js_arr);
layergroup.addLayer(layer.boundary_geom);

layergroup.addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(layergroup.getBounds());
```

After the map is displayed i have a button which calls `map.setView(....)`.
The problem is that if `fitbounds` is commented out `setview` works, if `fitbounds` is active then `setview` doesnot work.

Comment: looks like a problem with leaflet. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was problem of leaflet crashing when it had to draw many features. i called the `map.fitbounds` after 1 sec and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You have several mistakes in your code:

- You are using a factory method as a constructor. Instead of `var foo = new L.featureGroup()`, use `var foo = L.featureGroup()` or `var foo = new L.FeatureGroup()`. Note lowercase/uppercase! Leaflet coding style favours using factory methods (lowercase, no `new`).
- `layer` is not defined, so you cannot assign `layer.boundary_geom`.
- Your polygon coordinates have repeated coordinates. In practice this means that your polygon only has two vertices.
- The polygon coordinates are very close, only a few meters apart. When fitting to bounds, the map will hit `maxZoom`, and your polygon will appear to be just one point.

Once these are taken care of, [a demo map looks just fine](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/wer/1/edit?html,output), in both Leaflet 0.7.x and 1.0.0-beta.